# Datatable showing wrong page numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Following is the HTML code:

```
<table id="myTable" class="dTable1 contentList table table-bordered" style="z-index: 2; ">

                <thead id="tableHeader">
                    <tr id="headerRow">
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Event</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I am initializing the table on popup open using below JavaScript code:

```
showHistory = function (contentID) {
            debugger;
            var auditRes;
            //var oTable = $('#AuditListtable').dataTable();
            //oTable.fnDestroy();
            //alert("outside");
            $('#AuditListtable').dataTable({
                "sAjaxSource":SERVERURL?contentId=' + contentID,
                "aoColumns": [
           { "mData": "AccessDate" },
           {
               "mData": "EventDescription",
               "bSortable": false
           },
           {
               "mData": "IPAddress",
               "bSortable": false,
               "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                   debugger;
                   return '<td> <span title="' + data + '">Played By: ' + row.FirstName + ',  IP Address: ' + data + '</span></td>';
               }
           }
                ],
                "paging": true,
                "sDom": '<"top"p<"clear">>rt',
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "searching": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "processing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "order":true,
                "sServerMethod": "POST",
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "iDisplayLength": 8


            });
            $('#historyPopup').modal('show');

        }
```

The data will be populated in pop up. Currently we are having total 9 records but pagination is showing as 5 pages. After clicking on another page, it displays previous record. Table is not refreshed.

[image]

Comment: You've enabled server-side processing with `"bServerSide": true`. Most likely your response is incorrect. If you're indeed want server-side processing, your response should contain something like: `"iTotalRecords": "9", "iTotalDisplayRecords": "9"`. Please post your JSON response from the server.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com The issue was with the response. The response was sending iTotalRecords instead of iTotalDisplayRecords. Also the value of sEcho was hard coded. Can you please put your suggestions as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've enabled server-side processing with `"bServerSide": true`. Most likely your response is incorrect.

If you indeed want server-side processing, your response should be something like:

```js
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 9,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 9,
    "aaData": [
       // ... skipped ...
    ]
}
```

where `sEcho` should have the value of `sEcho` parameter from the request, `iTotalRecords` is number of all records **before** the filtering, and `iTotalDisplayRecords` is number of all records **after** the filtering.

See [server-side processing](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) for more information.